# Find indices of elements with equal values in a matrix (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find the indices of all the equal elements in a matrix (n×m). For each pair of the matching cells, I will perform a specific function on them. For example:

```
[ [2, 1, 3], [4, 1, 5], [2, 3, 2] ]
```

The cell (1, 1) whose value is 2 matches with cells (3, 1) and (3, 3). I tried to do this by looping through the whole matrix twice which is far away from being efficient O(n^2 * m^2). Is there a more efficient way to do this search (at least to avoid duplicates)? Please avoid using libraries like NumPy.
My code:

```
for i in range(n):
    for k in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            for l in range(m):
                if matrix[i][j] == matrix[k][l]:
                    sum += func((i + 1, j + 1), (k + 1, l + 1))
print(sum // 2)
```

Comment: Maybe it would be more efficient if you looped over `range(j, m)` in order to reduce the number of loops.

Comment: @CarySwoveland what is the point of 1) answering the question in an unrelated language, and 2) posting your answer as a comment?

Comment: @ddejohn, I sometimes offer a Ruby solution when there is no Ruby tag if I feel that I have a method of solution that has merit and that a reader familiar with the tagged language and Ruby (or who can figure out the gist of my Ruby code) might wish to offer an answer in the tagged language that builds on my approach. I do not post it as a solution because it does not answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to store all indices for each value like this:

```
lst = [[2, 1, 3], [4, 1, 5], [2, 3, 2]]

result = {}

for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst[i])):
        current = lst[i][j]
        if current in result:
            result[current].append((i + 1, j + 1))
        else:
            result[current] = [(i + 1, j + 1)]
        
result
```

The result is following dictionary storing the indices for all values:

```
{2: [(1, 1), (3, 1), (3, 3)],
 1: [(1, 2), (2, 2)],
 3: [(1, 3), (3, 2)],
 4: [(2, 1)],
 5: [(2, 3)]}
```

With this dictionary you can easily find values with multiple indices. One approach would be the following, where `y` contains all combinations of two duplicate values:

```
from itertools import combinations

for x in result.values():
    if (len(x) > 1):
        combis = combinations(x, 2)
        for y in combis:
            print(y)
```

Output:

```
((1, 1), (3, 1))
((1, 1), (3, 3))
((3, 1), (3, 3))
((1, 2), (2, 2))
((1, 3), (3, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I don't need their values in something other than checking for equality.

Comment: No problem! So, is your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Same idea as in Jano's answer,but [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as it seems as a use case for it.

Build a `dict` in which the 'keys' are lst elements and 'values' are a list of locations.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for i, sublst in enumerate(lst):
    for j, value in enumerate(sublst):
        result[value].append((i,j))
```

Then you can use `result` for whatever you want

```
>>> print('\n'.join(', '.join(str(location) for location in locations)
               for locations in result.values() if len(locations) > 1))
(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2)
(0, 1), (1, 1)
(0, 2), (2, 1)
```

Note:
Indexes are 0-based as per Python common usage.